# Update using cursor in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, cursor

I have two tables `department` and `employee`.

In the `department` table I have three columsn: `DEP_ID, NAME, HIKEINPERCENT`

In the `employee` table I have four columns: `EMP_ID, DEP_ID, EMP_NAME, SALARY`

Now if I update the `HIKEINPERCENT` in the `department` table, it should update the `SALARY` of the employees in the `employee` table by using CURSOR in SQL Server.

PLS GUIDE WITH EXPLANATION..

Comment: ***WHY*** with a cursor!?!?!?

Comment: @marc_s: cursors and all caps in questions often go together.

Comment: Avoid cursors in tsql if possible. In plsql they are good, but in tsql they are just a slow mess.

Comment: @SoonDead - Any stats on that? I would have assumed cursors are to be avoided in plsql too. One of the issues with cursors in TSQL is simply that cursors is an imperative approach whereas a declarative set based approach allows the query as a whole to be optimised.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a cursor. If you update the department HIKEINPERCENT field, you should have the DEP_ID to do so, something like :

```
update department set HIKEINPERCENT = @someNewValue where DEP_ID = @DepartementId
```

Then, you should update the SALARY in the employee table using something like :

```
update employee set SALARY = @SomeCrazyNewValue where DEP_ID = @DepartmentId
```

If this does not help you, please provide more specific info in the OP.